# redirect to previous page using branch.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, branch.io

After I click a link created by branch.io, iOS open the app, but when I switched to safari, it shows the blank page 'https://bnc.lt/end'(see screenshot 1). After I click back button **3** times, it goes back to the page with 'view in app' link. While switching the app, the safari in background always showing a popup 'Cannot Open Page', but this popup never shows when safari is open.

I understand there must be multiple redirection happening here. Is there a way to let user stays in previous page instead of a blank 'bnc.lt' page? Or is there a way, for example, run javascript to send the tracking data to branch.io and then open the app directly?

[image: blank page]
[image: cannot open page]

Comment: for others' edification: the interim solution is to not show the banner once has_app is true (docs on has_has app here: https://dev.branch.io/recipes/app_download_banner/#smart-banner-options-link-options). You can also employ $after_click_url to redirect back to the original page. Long-term, we may add the option to the web SDK's new web-to-app functionality to open in a new tab/window. (The new web-to-app functionality is described here: https://dev.branch.io/recipes/deep_link_mobile_site/)

Comment: Let us know if you have other questions